# import org.apache cannot be resolved error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I'm writing my map-reduce program in eclipse. Using Hadoop 2.6.0 version.

So I have downloaded hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz, unzipped and placed hadoop-2.6.0.jar file to /opt/eclipse/plugins with 777 permissions.

Secondly I have added location of the jar file in java build path in eclipse in external library. But am getting below error.

[image]

Can anyone share with me why its happening or what I'm missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse Plugin is not "The Hadoop Library"

I suggest you start over with a Maven project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Keep in mind - version 2.6.0 was released in 2014, so you might want to upgrade your cluster to at least a `2.7.x` version

Also, if running that on the cluster as a JAR file, you'd want to add `<scope>provided</scope>`

If you insist on using the JAR files, then you need the `hadoop-client-2.6.0.jar`